# CSSベンダープレフィクスを自動追加してくれる(特にperspective！)JavaScriptライブラリはないでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, css

読込だけで、CSSベンダープレフィクスを自動付与してくれるようなJavaScriptライブラリを探しています。
※ `perspective` プロパティに対応しているもの

- [cssFX](http://imsky.github.io/cssFx/) を試したら、`perspective` に対してプレフィクスは自動付与されず、該当項目がエラーとなりました
- コンパイル不要で、読込だけで、`perspective` にプレフィクスを付加してくれるライブラリはないでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cssFx のソースを見たら、簡単に足せそうだったのでやってみました。minified JSは以下のURLからダウンロードできるので、良かったら試してみてください。

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/koron/cssFx/support-perspective/cssfx.js

一応 [pull request はした](https://github.com/imsky/cssFx/pull/20) ので、もしかしたら取り込んでもらえるかもしれません。ただ非常に簡単な作業ですので、今後もっと必要なプロパティがあるようであれば、まずはご自身で足されることをオススメします。

---

#### 追記

その後PRが取り込まれましたので、本家の cssFx でも `perspective` にベンダープレフィックスが付くようになりました。

Comment: プレフィクス自動付与されることを確認できました。質問したら、pull request までしていただいて、しかもそれが、あっと言う間に取り込まれていた、という展開(の早さ)にびっくりしました。自分で足す、という発想は全くなかったのですが、思ったよりも簡単にできるのかも、と思いました。大変参考になりましたー